# how to disable RPS1 when in midnight commander

Tags: zsh

Because it is ugly displaying RPS1 under mc.

I try to

```
alias mc="(RPS1='' ; /usr/bin/mc)"
```

But, it can NOT work.

Comment: I've tried to use SHLVL to check, but in different environment, the SHLVL is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `/proc/$PPID/exe` pointss to `mc` and unset it.

Comment: I like this tip, but could you show a sample zshrc? It is difficult to me to check if the link is point to mc.

Comment: @DanielYCLin You can test like this: `[[ /proc/$PPID/exe -ef /usr/bin/mc ]]`. `-ef` means to check if the two operands point to the same file.